# Can someone please help me in drawing the below diagram via tikz (for my master thesis)

Tags: tikz-pgf

The diagram I wish to be drawn via tikz is attached below. I am new to LaTeX and would very much appreciate the help!

[image]

Comment: Do you really need those ugly parentheses?

Answer (score 5):

[image: The requested vectors drawn in tikz]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[rounded corners=0.4cm] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 5);
        \fill[fill=white] (0.3, -0.1) rectangle (0.7, 0.1);
        \fill[fill=white] (0.3, 4.9) rectangle (0.7, 5.1);
        \node at (0.5, 4) {\(P_1\)};
        \node at (0.5, 3) {\(P_2\)};
        \node at (0.5, 2) {\(\vdots\)};
        \node at (0.5, 1) {\(P_p\)};
        \node[text width=2.5cm] at (1, -1) {Process\\characteristics};
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
            \draw[rounded corners=0.4cm] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 5);
            \fill[fill=white] (0.3, -0.1) rectangle (0.7, 0.1);
            \fill[fill=white] (0.3, 4.9) rectangle (0.7, 5.1);
            \node at (0.5, 4) {\(T_1\)};
            \node at (0.5, 3) {\(T_2\)};
            \node at (0.5, 2) {\(\vdots\)};
            \node at (0.5, 1) {\(T_t\)};
            \node[text width=2.5cm] at (1, -1) {Technical\\characteristics};
        \end{scope}
        \node at (2, 2.5) {\(\longleftrightarrow\)};
        \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
            \draw[rounded corners=0.4cm] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 5);
            \fill[fill=white] (0.3, -0.1) rectangle (0.7, 0.1);
            \fill[fill=white] (0.3, 4.9) rectangle (0.7, 5.1);
            \node at (0.5, 4) {\(S_1\)};
            \node at (0.5, 3) {\(S_2\)};
            \node at (0.5, 2) {\(\vdots\)};
            \node at (0.5, 1) {\(S_p\)};
            \node[text width=2.5cm] at (1, -1) {Service\\characteristics};
        \end{scope}
        \node at (5, 2.5) {\(\longleftrightarrow\)};
        \node at (7, -2) {(Quality/Price)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is one way of doing it in `tikz`. Since it's just the same thing repeated I used scopes to shift the copies to the right places. Note that the brackets in this case are actually rectangles with rounded corners and the top and bottom covered in white. Therefore if you want to view this on any background other than white you will have to change the colour of the covering rectangles.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

One more solution, with use of `arrows.meta` and `positioning` Ti*k*Z libraries, package `amsmath` with `matrix` math environment used for writenf of nodes contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 22mm,
            > = Straight Barb,
 every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, <->, 
                      shorten < = 1.5em, shorten > = 1.5em},
every label/.style = {label distance=1em, text width=7em, align=center},
N/.style = {inner sep=1em, align=center, 
            append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
            \draw[rounded corners=1.5ex, semithick]
                ([xshift=-1em] \LN.north) -| (\LN.west) |-
                ([xshift=-1em] \LN.south)
                ([xshift=+1em] \LN.north) -| (\LN.east) |-
                ([xshift=+1em] \LN.south);
              }}}
                        ]  
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}                        
\node (n1) [N, label=below:Process Characteristic]  
                {$\begin{matrix}
                    P_1\\ P_2\\  \vdots\\ P_p
                 \end{matrix}$};
\node (n2) [N, right=of n1,
               label=below:Technical Characteristic ] 
                {$\begin{matrix}
                    T_1\\ T_2\\  \vdots\\ T_p
                 \end{matrix}$};
\node (n3) [N, right=of n2,
               label=below:{Service Characteristic (Quality/Price)} ]
                {$\begin{matrix}
                    S_1\\ S_2\\  \vdots\\ S_p
                 \end{matrix}$};
\path   (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason for using Ti*k*Z

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\underlabel}[2]{%
  \underset{\text{\footnotesize\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\\#1\end{tabular}}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\widepmatrix}[1]{%
  \left(
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
    \begin{array}{c} #1 \end{array}
  \right)
}
\underlabel{Process \\ characteristics}
 {\widepmatrix{P_1 \\ P_2 \\ \vdots \\ P_p}}
\longleftrightarrow
\underlabel{Technical \\ characteristics}
 {\widepmatrix{T_1 \\ T_2 \\ \vdots \\ T_t}}
\longleftrightarrow
\underlabel{Service \\ characteristics \\ (Quality/price)}
 {\widepmatrix{S_1 \\ S_2 \\ \vdots \\ S_s}}
\]

\end{document}
```

The auxiliary commands are defined only in the display, but if you have other objects like those in your document, you can move the definitions in the preamble.

[image]